# Mysql query first element info as well as last element count

Tags: mysql

I have a table (series) and I want to get a series first episode info as well as its last available season and episode.
I was able to accomplish this using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `video`.*, 
    `cat`.`en_title` categoryName, 
    `cat`.`id` categoryNb, 
    `cat`.`ar_title` category_ar_title, 
    `cat`.`en_title` category_en_title,
    MAX(`video2`.`season`) LatestSeason,
    MAX(`video2`.`episodeNumber`) LatestEpisode
FROM 
    (`video_item` video, 
     `category` cat, 
     `video_item_category` video_cat,
     `video_item` video2)
WHERE 
    `video2`.`rootSeries` = `video`.`id`
    AND `video_cat`.`video_itemId` = video.id
    AND `video_cat`.`categoryId` = cat.id
    AND (`video`.published = 1)
    AND `video`.`rootSeries` = 0
    AND (video.kind =2)
    AND (video.seriesRating not in (-1))
GROUP BY 
    `video`.`id`
ORDER BY 
    `video`.`season` asc, `video`.`episodeNumber` asc, `video`.`updateDateTime` desc
LIMIT 
    15
```

I used self join and max function to append the last season and episode to the first episode info results. but the numbers are note quite correct, you see I have a column 'published' and the returned max values are not filtered by it.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using self join and a sub-query:

```
SELECT 
    `video`.*, 
    `cat`.`en_title` categoryName, 
    `cat`.`nb` categoryNb, 
    `cat`.`ar_title` category_ar_title, 
    `cat`.`en_title` category_en_title,
    `video2`.`LatestSeason` ,
    `video2`.`LatestEpisode` 
FROM 
    (`video_item` video, 
     `category` cat, 
     `video_item_category` video_cat)
join (select 
        rootSeries, 
        MAX(season) LatestSeason, 
        MAX(episodeNummer)LatestEpisode 
    from 
        video_item
    where
        published = 1
    GROUP BY 
        id
    ) video2 on `video2`.`rootSeries` = `video`.`id`
WHERE 
    `video_cat`.`video_itemId` = video.id
    AND `video_cat`.`category_Id` = cat.id
    AND (`video`.published = 1)
    AND `video`.`rootSeries` = 0
    AND (video.kind =2)
    AND (video.seriesRating not in (-1))
GROUP BY 
    `video`.`id`
ORDER BY 
    `video`.`season` asc, `video`.`episodeNummer` asc,     `video`.`updateDateTime` desc
LIMIT 
    15
```